# Python to excel

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping

I created a script to pull data from a website and paste it in excel. The script works, however when I extract the Name from the website and it paste in excel for some reason its very small. But when you click in the cell its normal size. See image here.

I tried to show a snip it as an example but stack won't allow me.

Here is the current code

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Fetch the HTML page

url = 'https://esearch.mobilecopropertytax.com/Property/View/466089'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text

# Parse the HTML page
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# Find the element containing the Parcel Number
element = soup.find('th', text='Parcel Number:')

# Extract the Parcel Number from the element
parcel_number = element.find_next_sibling().text

# Find the element containing the Name
element = soup.find('th', text='Name:')

# Extract the Name from the element
name = element.find_next_sibling().text

# Load the workbook
wb = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\user\EJW Test\EJWtest.xlsx')

# Select the sheet
ws = wb['Justification Worksheet']

# Select the cells
cell1 = ws['C7'] # Parcel Number
cell2 = ws['C10'] # Name

# Set the values of the cells
cell1.value = parcel_number
cell2.value = name

# Save the workbook
wb.save('completetest.xlsx')
```

Unsure why it puts the parcel info in just fine but inserts the name into excel and it looks completely different.

Comment: So check and correct the formatting for that cell / name.

Comment: My question is why would it insert the data with no issue into one cell but not insert the same into the other. They are both the same font and text so I don't understand how it changing. Also when you just click inside the cell the its fine. But when you click out it goes back to small letters.

Comment: check the cell: format - alignment - untick "Shrink to fit"

Comment: This worked. Thanks man. cell1.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center', shrink_to_fit=False)
cell2.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center', shrink_to_fit=False)